# Android: try block is not being entered

Tags: android

I downloaded a WavFile package from http://www.labbookpages.co.uk/audio/javaWavFiles.html

Using which i wanted to read the data block of a given *.wav file. 
Hence i created a new package in my android project and added those class files and used then in my android project. the code snippet is shown below:

```
          File f=new File("/sdcard/", "a.wav");
          Log.d(TAG, "File found");

            WavFile fp;
    try {
        fp = WavFile.openWavFile(f);
        Log.d(TAG, "Wav file found");
                    //Displays info about wav file
        fp.display();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (WavFileException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

There are no errors in my program but when executed the out is only the first log msg and not the log msg within the try block. Also there is no exception occouring here. Can anyone pls tell me whats the problem with this. or provide another way to retrieve data from a wav file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: put log in both exception, and also put catch block for "Exception"

Comment: Thank you rajpara There was an  IOException. Do u Know what might possibly be the reason for this

Comment: by calling new File it constructs a new File using the specified directory path and file name, it doesn't mean that it has wav content, so if your a.wav file don't contain data and your openWavFile try to fetch wav details from the file header. so it throw IO exception , as per my understanding, read openWavFile method description , you will get idea

Comment: @rajpara Hey new creates a new file its true, Then how do i get reference to file a.wav saved on sdcard i tried this              File dir=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();                  File f=new File(dir,"a.wav"); But his didnt work... Pls tell some way i can access my file present in sdcard or a file present in the /res/raw/ folder

Comment: is your "a.wav" file stored in sdcard at root or in any folder ??

Comment: Hey i got the solution actually i had stored the file in /mnt and not in sdcard so accordingly i then pushed the file from mnt to /mnt/sdcard and now the below answer is working...   Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file location is not right.

Open file from sdcard as follows:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "a.wav");
```

Or put your file "a.wav" in /res/raw folder in your project
and open it in MediaPlayer as follows:

```
  MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.a);
  mp.start();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i'm not opening it via a mediaplayer, i need to open it as an object of type "File". The first one is also giving an IOException.

Comment: Did u try to debug your application? In which line is exception?

Comment: Try please with another wav file. Maybe problem is in file

Comment: Hey i'm unable to get reference itself.                           File dir=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();               File f=new File(dir,"a.wav"); if(!f.exists()) Log.d(TAG,"File not exists");  The output is File not exists it means i'm unable to get a reference. Or can u pls tell me if there is a way to get reference to a file which is present in /res/raw/ folder///

Comment: Hey i got the solution actually i had stored the file in /mnt and not in /sdcard so accordingly i then pushed the file from mnt to /mnt/sdcard and now the first option is working fine. Thank you very much......  :)